# Python SWIG: Python module #define attributes differ from internal C defines

Tags: python, runtime, swig

I'm using SWIG to wrap for Python the sources of C library I developed. Depending on the deployment platform, some compile time definitions are used to overwrite the default library parameters, which are contained in a few headerfiles.

My problem is that, even though when using the different wrapped functions in the model the outcome is as expected(using the non-default parameters), whenever I access the wrapped #defines in the generated module, the returned value is always the default.

This is a simplifed version of my setup:

offset.h

```
#ifndef FIRST_OFFSET
#define FIRST_OFFSET      10
#endif

int get_first_offset(void);
```

offset.c

```
#include "offset.h"
int get_first_offset(void) {
     return FIRST_OFFSET;
}
```

offset.i

```
%module Offset
%{
    #include "offset.h"
}

%inline %{
    // Some helpers
}

%include include/offset.h
```

setup.py

```
#Previous code
ext_modules = Extension(name="_Offset",
                        include_dirs=["include"]
                        define_macros=[('FIRST_OFFSET','20')],
                        sources=["offset.i", "offset.c"],
                        language="c")
setup(name=name, version=version, ext_modules=[ext_modules])
```

test.py

```
import Offset

print(str(Offset.FIRST_OFFSET))
print(str(Offset.get_first_offset()))
```

Console output:

```
10
20
```

Is there some way to get `Offset.FIRST_OFFSET` to match `Offset.get_first_offset()`? I would like to be able to access the value directly from the wrapped #define, as currently I am writing similar wrapper functions to get_x_offset, which is not scalable :(!

EDIT: Added offset.i file

Comment: Probably in offset.i you need to %include whatever file defines FIRST_OFFSET, but you've not quite shown enough code to be sure exactly what's going on.

Comment: @Flexo, I do %include the headerfile offset.h, I updated the simplified version of the interface file. Any other clues I could give you? I'm not sure exactly what else I could show